# Different roles for different File Plan parts in Alfresco Records Management

Tags: alfresco, record

From what I'm able to understand (and test), there's really no way to setup a single user in a way in which that user would be able to edit metadata in one part of the File Plan, and NOT be able to edit metadata in another part of the File Plan.

In other words, when a user assumes a role (User, Manager, Power User), that role is applied to every part of the file plan the user has permissions for, no exceptions. Basically, a user can assume only one role in the Records Management site.

Can anyone confirm this, and give some reasoning behind this decision?